# combining strings from the selected previous rows in the panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe originally read in from excel as follows 
Input:
[Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwbgO.png)

I would like to transform it as follows,

Output:
[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6T1A.png)

Can you please help me how can i do this with panda?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility you can use, is by creating groups of rows based on the headings. Here is the example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Type": [ "Heading", "item", "item", "Heading", "item", "item" ],
    "Name": [ "construction", "cement", "sand", "fruit", "apple", "orange" ],
    "Count": [ 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 78 ]
})

# Creating groups based on Type == "Heading"
df["group_id"] = ( df.Type == "Heading" ).cumsum()

# Output:
#       Type          Name  Count  group_id
# 0  Heading  construction      0         1
# 1     item        cement      3         1
# 2     item          sand      0         1
# 3  Heading         fruit      0         2
# 4     item         apple      7         2
# 5     item        orange     78         2

# For each group, set to all rows the respective heading
df = df.groupby("group_id")
df = df.apply(lambda p: p.assign(Heading=p.Name[ p.Type == "Heading" ].values[0]))
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Output:
#       Type          Name  Count  group_id       Heading
# 0  Heading  construction      0         1  construction
# 1     item        cement      3         1  construction
# 2     item          sand      0         1  construction
# 3  Heading         fruit      0         2         fruit
# 4     item         apple      7         2         fruit
# 5     item        orange     78         2         fruit

# Transforming the name, and selecting right rows
df["Name"] = df.Heading + ': ' + df.Name
df.loc[ df.Type != "Heading", ["Type", "Name", "Count"]]

# Output:
#    Type                  Name  Count
# 1  item  construction: cement      3
# 2  item    construction: sand      0
# 4  item          fruit: apple      7
# 5  item         fruit: orange     78
```

Pipeline'd version:

```
df \
    .assign(group_id=lambda p: ( p.Type == "Heading" ).cumsum()) \
    .groupby("group_id") \
    .apply(lambda p: p.assign(Heading=p.Name[ p.Type == "Heading" ].values[0])) \
    .reset_index(drop=True) \
    .assign(Name=lambda p: p.Heading + ': ' + p.Name) \
    .query("Type != 'Heading'") \
    .get([ "Type", "Name", "Count" ])
```

Answer (score 1):

DACbuilder,

Here is a quick working example for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    ['heading', 'toys', ],
    ['item', 'car', 4],
    ['item', 'bike', 3],
    ['heading', 'food', ],
    ['item', 'apple', 2],
    ['item', 'orange', 5]],
    columns=('type', 'name', 'cnt'))  # sample data

df.loc[df.type=='heading','heading'] = df.name  # create column with headings

df.heading.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)  # fill headings down for corresponding items

df.loc[df.type=='item', 'name'] = df.heading + ': ' + df.name  # combine headings with names

df.loc[df.type=='item', ['name','cnt']]  # this is the desired output

           name  cnt
1     toys: car  4.0
2    toys: bike  3.0
4   food: apple  2.0
5  food: orange  5.0
```